# Assign only one part of a bitset keeping the other one unchangeable

Tags: bitmap, bit-manipulation, bitset

## Preview

Suppose we have a register - some binary word of a fixed size `0bXXXXXXXX`.
Next suppose that we use only some part of this register `0bUUXXUUXX`(`U` for "use", `X` for "don't care").

For example, I am using two registers: `DDRD` and `DDRB` on ATMega328 to control [seven-segment display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display). As far as those registers are eight bit registers and display has only seven (I am not using the dot) pins to control some bits of those registers are out of the story and I do not want to change them while control the display. So I have to manipulate only those bits that I need and keep the current values of those that I do not need. So far I have reached to the following solution.

## Solution

This is `C` code (though there is not so much code) but the idea is language-independent I think.

First of all I define a part mask that emphasize what bits of a register will be used. In my case register is 8-bit length and I use bits `[4:7]`.

```
#define      USE_MSK 0b11110000  //bits out of use are set to 0's here
```

Then when I need to set bits that I use (i.e. bits `[4:7]`) to, say,`1001` I do

```
#define      CHANGE_TO 0b10011111 //bits out of use are set to 1's here
```

and then

```
register |= USE_MSK;
register &= CHANGE_TO;
```

Actually I use a temporary variables in order to change register in one assignment.

The question is what improvement is possible here? Or it should be a different way at all. Any critic and/or advice are welcome.